# Heroku mLab MongoDB add-on vs MongoDB Atlas

Tags: mongodb, heroku

I am using MongoDB Atlas with my Heroku app.

I have seen that there is an mLab MongoDB add-on on Heroku, as [mLab is part MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.mlab.com/mlab-to-atlas/) now, was is the advantage of using this add-on ?

Moreover, the add-on looks like a more expensive solution than MongoDB Atlas...

Answer (score 1):

You should use the new MongoDB Atlas Heroku app. mLab heroku app will be deprecated when the migration done, see the [doc](https://docs.mlab.com/mlab-to-atlas/#heroku-addon) from migrating from mLab to Atlas

> MongoDB plans to build an integration between MongoDB Atlas and Heroku. You will be able to continue to use mLab via its add-on at Heroku until the new integration is available.

Comment: This is not really answering my question: I am already using Heroku and Atlas without add-on on my app, my question is what is the advantage to link Heroku and Atlas with the mLab add-on?

Answer (score 1):

Now this add on feature is no more useful as mlab has already been acquired by MongoDB.

Earlier the purpose of this feature was that the mLab Add-on used to be co-located with your application in case you have selected this option and could help in reducing the latency of your application as `mlab` was available primarily in US regions.

But now mlab has been acquired by MongoDB and you can deploy Atlas cluster in the same region of your application to reduce the latency.

I hope this answer your question.